# If the US source of protein changed from animal to vegetable tomorrow, how much of what types of plants would need to be planted?

Tags: veganism

Humans need specific things in their diets, in the US much of that is met through meat and dairy products. If everyone in the US went vegan tomorrow, how much of what new crops would need to be farmed to meet the same needs now filled by meat and dairy products?

Comment: try worldbuilding.SE honestly

Comment: The question is ON TOPIC because it has to do with knowledge of biological and ecological relations between our consumption and environment. This kind of knowledge is what guide vegans to make campaigns, scientists to research, politicians to make policies and consumers to make choices.